# Find the real solutions for the system: $ x^3+y^3=1$,$x^2y+2xy^2+y^3=2.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

> Find the real solutions for the system:
>   $$\left\{
> \begin{array}{l}
> x^3+y^3=1\\ 
> x^2y+2xy^2+y^3=2\\ 
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $$

From a book with exercises for math contests. The solutions provided are: $(x,y)=(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}})$ and $(\dfrac{1}{3^{\frac{2}{3}}},\dfrac{2}{3^{\frac{2}{3}}})$.
Working with the expressions I could find that an equivalent system is 
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=1\\ 
y(x+y)^2=2\\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Developing these expressions I got stuck.

Hints and answers are appreciated. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply the first equation by $2$ and then set the two left sides equal:

$$2x^3+2y^3 = x^2y+2xy^2+y^3.$$

This is a homogeneous equation of degree $3$, so divide through by $x^3$:

$$2+2\frac{y^3}{x^3} = \frac{y}{x}+2\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{y^3}{x^3}.$$

Substitute $u=y/x$:

$$2+2u^2=u+2u^2+u^3$$

$$u^3-2u^2-u+2=0$$

$$(u^2-1)(u-2)=0$$

$$u=-1, 1 \mbox{ or } 2.$$

Dividing the first equation by $x^3$ gives $1+u^3 = 1/x^3.$  Plug each value of $u$ into this to find values of $x$ and then $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Observe that $xy\ne0$

Set $y=mx$

divide the resultant one equation by the other to form a cubic equation in $m$ with $m+1\ne0$ being one factor

Comment: This will work Homogeneous Polynomials having the same degree

Answer (score 1):

Well, the second equation is a quadratic equation in $x$:

$$\text{a}\cdot x^2+\text{b}\cdot x+\text{c}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{-\text{b}\pm\sqrt{\text{b}^2-4\cdot\text{a}\cdot\text{c}}}{2\cdot\text{a}}\tag1$$

Now, in your example $\text{a}=\text{y},\text{b}=2\cdot\text{y}^2,\text{c}=\text{y}^3-2$, so we get:

$$x=\frac{-2\cdot\text{y}^2\pm\sqrt{\left(2\cdot\text{y}^2\right)^2-4\cdot\text{y}\cdot\left(\text{y}^3-2\right)}}{2\cdot\text{y}}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\text{y}}}-\text{y}\tag2$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$x^3+y^3 = 1$

$x^2y+2xy^2+y^3 = 2$

Taking $y^3$ common from LHS on both sides, we get

$y^3(x^3/y^3 +1) = 1$

$y^3(x^2/y^2+2x/y+1) = 2$

$\therefore \frac{y^3(x^3/y^3 +1)}{y^3(x^2/y^2+2x/y+1)}=\frac{1}{2} $

$\therefore \frac{x^3/y^3 +1}{x^2/y^2+2x/y+1}=\frac{1}{2} $

On substituting x/y = m, we get

$$\frac{m^3 +1}{m^2+2m+1}=\frac{1}{2} $$
On cross-multiplication
$$2m^3 +2 = m^2+2m+1 $$
$\therefore 2m^3-m^2-2m+1 = 0$

By hit and trial as sum of coefficients is one, $m=1$ is one root
Hence,

$2m^3-2m^2+m^2-m-m+1=0$

$2m^2(m-1)+m(m-1)-1(m-1)=0$

$(m-1)(2m^2+m-1)=0$

$(m-1)(2m-1)(m+1)=0$

$\therefore m = \pm 1, 1/2 $
i.e. $ If m = 1, x/y =1 \therefore x=y$

Hence from first equation
$x^3+x^3 =1 $
$2x^3=1$
$x^3=\frac{1}{2}$
$x=\frac{1}{2^{1/3}}$
$y=\frac{1}{2^{1/3}}$
m = -1 is not possible as it is not satisfying the equation

For m=1/2,
$x/y = 1/2, 2x=y, \therefore x^3+ (2x)^3 = 1 $
$9x^3=1, x=1/3^{2/3}, y =\frac{2}{3^{2/3}}$
Hence required solution set is

$${(\frac{1}{2^{1/3}}, \frac{1}{2^{1/3}}),(\frac{1}{3^{2/3}},\frac{2}{3^{2/3}})}$$