# Find the real solutions for the system: $x^2+4xy-2y^2=5(x+y)$, $ 5x^2-xy-y^2=7(x+y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

> Find all real solutions for the system:
>   $$\left\{
> \begin{array}{l}
> x^2+4xy-2y^2=5(x+y)\\ 
> 5x^2-xy-y^2=7(x+y)\\ 
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $$
>   This is from a math olympiad training book. No answer provided.

It is easy to spot that $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is a solution, by inspection. But I'm not being able to find other solutions, if they exist. I tried all tricks I know but was not getting to anything useful.

Hints and answers are appreciated. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E2%2B4xy%E2%88%922y%5E2%3D5(x%2By),5x%5E2%E2%88%92xy%E2%88%92y%5E2%3D7(x%2By)) gives the solutions as $x=-4,y=-12$; $x=0,y=0$; and $x=3,y=2$

Comment: Turns into this equation $0=18x^2-33xy+9y^2$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544262/find-the-real-solutions-for-the-system-x3y3-1-x2y2xy2y3-2/2544264#2544264

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\begin{align*}5\times\text{Eq.(2)}-7\times\text{Eq.(1)} \equiv 18x^2-33xy+9y^2=0 \\\equiv (y-3x)(3y-2x)=0\\\implies y=\frac{2x}{3} \text{ and } y=3x\end{align*}$$

Substituting $y=3x$ into $\text{Eq.(1)}$, we have, $$x^2+12x^2-2(9x^2)=5(4x) \implies x^2+4x=0 \\\implies \boxed{(x=0, y=0) \text{ and } (x=-4, y= -12)}$$

Similarly, $y=\frac{2x}{3}$ gives us, $$x^2+\frac{8x^2}{3}-\frac{8x^2}{9}=5(\frac{5x}{3}) \implies x^2-3x=0 \\\implies \boxed{(x=0,y=0) \text{ and } (x=3, y=2)}$$

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Multiply the first equation by $7$ and the second by $5$ than subtract and you find (as suggested in the comment of Benjamin  Moss) the equation
$$
18x^2-33xy+9y^2=0
$$

that is a homogeneous equation that can be solved with the substitution
$y=kx$

Answer (score 1):

This is an intersection of two hyperbolae. The right hand side is the shift. Personally, I would first try to combine equations and substitute so that it simplifies as much as possible. For instance, the right hand side shifts in a particular direction, so if we rotate the coordinates by $45^\circ$:

$$x=u+v$$
$$y=u-v$$

we get the system of equations

$$3u^2+6uv-5v^2=10u$$
$$3u^2+12uv+5v^2=14u$$

If you add these equations and divide by $u$, you get:

$$6u+18v=24$$
$$u+3v=4$$
which is a straight line.

Now you can directly put this into any of the previous two equations and solve it as a quadratic equation.

For instance, expressing $u=4-3v$ and putting it into the first equation, you obtain
$$2v^2-9v+4=0$$
$$(2v-1)(v-4)=0$$

$$v=\{4,1/2\}$$

Now you just put this back into $u$ and then $x$ and $y$.